# Sum of digits of divisors

Tags: mathematics

Psd(x) denotes the sum of digits of all positive integer divisors of x where x>0. For example, Psd(15)=1+3+5+1+5=14 (divisors: 1,3,5,15)

What is x for the biggest value of Psd(x) where x<10000.

Comment: I would bet on 7560 or 9240, both of which have 64 divisors.  I don't see a good way to be certain without a brute force search.

Comment: So you're looking for the largest perfect number <10000?

Comment: no, function is not exactly largest perfect number.

Comment: Maybe a program could solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple Python bruteforce program that gets the job done:

```
from math import sqrt

maxNum = -1
maxSum = 0
for x in range(1, 10000):
  currentSum = 0
  for d in range(1, int(sqrt(x)) + 1):
    if(x % d == 0):
      for digit in str(d):
        currentSum += int(digit)
      for digit in str(x / d):
        currentSum += int(digit)
  if currentSum > maxSum:
    maxSum = currentSum
    maxNum = x

print "Maximum sum: {}.\n{}:".format(maxSum, maxNum)
for d in range(1, int(sqrt(maxNum)) + 1):
  if(maxNum % d == 0):
    print "  = {} x {}".format(d, maxNum / d)
```

Output:

```
Maximum sum: 549.
7920:
  = 1 x 7920
  = 2 x 3960
  = 3 x 2640
  = 4 x 1980
  = 5 x 1584
  = 6 x 1320
  = 8 x 990
  = 9 x 880
  = 10 x 792
  = 11 x 720
  = 12 x 660
  = 15 x 528
  = 16 x 495
  = 18 x 440
  = 20 x 396
  = 22 x 360
  = 24 x 330
  = 30 x 264
  = 33 x 240
  = 36 x 220
  = 40 x 198
  = 44 x 180
  = 45 x 176
  = 48 x 165
  = 55 x 144
  = 60 x 132
  = 66 x 120
  = 72 x 110
  = 80 x 99
  = 88 x 90
```

Good guess @Ross Millikan.

Comment: @Oray I barely released my mouse button before you accepted it. Nice reflexes lol.